# How do I post to a website using roblox HttpService?

Tags: node.js, post, lua, roblox

So, I'm trying to create a game that will post to my Cloudflare Tunnels website. I want to obtain a code from the website and post the user's username to the site. Here's my Roblox server code:

```lua
local rs = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local msgRe = rs:WaitForChild("MsgRe")
local httpSrv = game:GetService("HttpService")

local function getObbyCode(player)
    local url = "https://headset-breast-derek-registered.trycloudflare.com/obbyCode5"
    local response = httpSrv:GetAsync(url)
    local data = httpSrv:JSONDecode(response)
    print("data = ", data)
    local code = tostring(data.code)
    msgRe:FireClient(player, code)
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(getObbyCode)
```

Here is the client code in a ScreenGui:

```lua
local rs = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local msgRe = rs:WaitForChild("MsgRe")
local lbl = script.Parent

local function displayMsg(code, text)
    lbl.Text = text .. code
end

msgRe.OnClientEvent:Connect(displayMsg)
```

And here is my node.js code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");

app.get('/obbyCode5', (req, res) =>{
    let code = "OBBY$" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    console.log("code: ", code);
    fs.appendFile('codes', "\n" + code + " amount: 5", function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('Appended!');
     });
    res.json({
        code: code,
        amount: "5"
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: But what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried [HttpService:RequestAsync](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/HttpService#RequestAsync) or [PostAsync](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/HttpService#PostAsync)?

Comment: i dont know how to use HttpService:RequestAsync or PostAsync